# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "fact_spv_commissioned_lot";

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have looked at a few similar questions on stackoverflow but none of it helped me. I keep on getting this error no matter what I do.

Amazon Invalid operation: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "fact_spv_commissioned_lot";

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staging_serials s
  JOIN dim_md_company c ON (c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid)
  JOIN staging_product p ON (s.compositeproductcode = p.compositeproductcode)
  JOIN dim_packaging_level l ON (l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom)
WHERE c.sk_company_id = fact_spv_commissioned_lot.sk_company_id
  AND s.lotnumber = fact_spv_commissioned_lot.lot_number
  and p.sk_product_id = fact_spv_commissioned_lot.sk_product_id
  and l.sk_packaging_level_id = fact_spv_commissioned_lot.sk_packaging_level_id
```

Comment: Well, it's obvious isn't it? The table `fact_spv_commissioned_lot` is not listed anywhere in the `FROM` (and JOIN`) clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `fact_spv_commissioned_lot` is not listed in the table clause of the query.  You're joining `staging_serials`, `dim_md_company`, `staging_product`, and `dim_packaging_level` tables.  You need to include `fact_spv_commissioned_lot` table.